# Extract or import two Specific values form Text file - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, textscan

I am working on a problem in MATLAB, in which I need to import two specific values (highlighted) from a text file as shown in the figure 1.

[image: figure 1]

Corresponding .txt file is attached in the following link ([Link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/411819-extract-or-import-two-specific-values-form-text-file))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to extract specific values from a text file you should always consider using regular expressions.

For getting the two values you highlighted you can use:

```
raw = fileread('M7_soil_FN_1.txt');
val = regexp(raw,'(\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(?=NPTS)','tokens')
```

The regular expression says:

- `(\d+)` Match digits and capture.
- `\s+` Match whitespace.
- `(\d+\.\d+)` Match and capture digits, a full stop, more digits.
- `\s+` Match whitespace.
- `(?=NPTS)` Positive lookahead to ensure that what follows is NPTS.

Then convert val to double:

```
val = str2double(val{:})
>>val(1)

    5991

>>val(2)

    0.0050
```

If you are interested, you can see the regular expression in action live [here](https://regex101.com/r/plJrSj/1).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work.

```
delimiter = ' ';
startRow = 7;
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');     
formatSpec = '%f%f%[^\n\r]';
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec,startRow-startRow+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
val1 = dataArray{1,1};
val2 = dataArray{1,2};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is not working. It is starting at 7th row but, dataArray is giving me a combination of doubles and cells, I am unable to extract two values specifically

Comment: I think there's need to be some modification. Can you upload the data in the question? Just remove the image and put the actual texts from the .txt file.

Comment: text file attached, please find